# Bootstrap-datetimepicker: Arrows do not work with restricted hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

[image]

I'm working with http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. I have allowing only selected hours by using:

```
enabledHours: [ 12,19,20,21 ],
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qqp6nwcd/1/

When the datetimepicker opens the initial value is set to 12Pm which is allowed but the scrolling of the hours does not work because the next valid time is 19:00 hours. Is there anyway to allow hour scrolling by just skipping over the disallowed hours so that one upward click goes from 12:00 to 19:00?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                enabledHours: [ 12,19,20,21 ],
                stepping:15,
                sideBySide: true,
                defaultDate:false
            });
        });
    </script>
```